# JavaScript Countdown (counting up) milliseconds too quick, wont load next page?

Tags: php, javascript, performance, setinterval, countdown

javascript too fast when i set  `setInterval(function()` down (or up i guess, speed wise) to `100` or `500` and wont load `mypage.php` as it doesn't have time i think? don't want to slow counter down either. so is there a php equivalent that can? (with the little number display like this, see jsfiddle) or is there a better javascript counter ? would prefer php, any ideas?

Thanks heaps, any help would be great.

Changed the page link to `#` as it will freeze things otherwise 
http://jsfiddle.net/aEXgB/2/  Also added `exit;`but didn't help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown() {
   var i = document.getElementById('counter');
   if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)>=3000) {
       location.href = 'mypage.php';
       exit;
   }
   i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)+1;
}
setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },.75);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="margin-left:20px; float:left;"><p>Countdown:<font color="#33CC00"> <span     id="counter">10 </span></font></p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you do realize you're refreshing the page on every loop, right? (see the stop/refresh button of your browser on your fiddle page)

Comment: Wow, chrome bug. Cant close the page anymore.

Comment: Sorry guys :) didn't fix quick enough, try to, the second i relised i posted the wrong jsfiddle

Comment: setInterval takes an integer argument, not a float.  I'd expect that setting it to .75 will make JS round it to 1 and execute the interval event every 1 time units.  As the time units used by setinterval are microseconds.... if you want a 3/4 second delay then you need to setinterval to 750, not .75

Comment: yeah i know changed before ... sorry about that. (still to quick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },.75);
```

with

```
var t = setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },.75);
```

then just before the exit in the function, add;

```
clearInterval(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
var sec = 0;
var interval = 750; // milliseconds
var stop = 5; // seconds
function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
setInterval( function(){
     if(document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML <  stop) {
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
     } else {
        location.href = 'http://google.nl'
     }
}, interval);
```

Html:

```
<div id="seconds></div>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5tM3A/5/

Comment: And to make that fast? and load mypage.php?

Comment: add an interval variable (milliseconds).

Comment: Between the brackets you can do what ever you want. But loading a page every 0.75 seconds maybe not the best thing you can do..

Comment: was never the goal :) just for the counter to stop and load  the new page

Comment: Edit the script for you. Now you can add a stop time. If the stop time is passed you redirect the to another page. Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't understand why it's called a countdown when you count UP.

Second, I think it's better to update the counter and THEN check the value.  That way you don't have an extra call to the `coundown` function.

Third, clear the interval before changing location because the interval is probably getting fired again too quickly.

Fourth, this won't actually work in jsfiddle because of how jsfiddle uses iframes :)

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },.75);
function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)+1;
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)>=3000) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        window.location.href = "mypage.php";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a countdown script reversed :) wont work because of iframes on just jsfiddle or in any iframe ? what about embed ?

Comment: You can also set `parseInt(i.innerHTML) + 1` to a variable so you don't have to parse twice :)

Comment: If this script was in an iframe, I think you would need `window.parent.location.href`.